# How to change timestamp format of wikipedia page's last modified section

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

From various [API:Client code](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code) I am using [mediawiki-js](https://github.com/brettz9/mediawiki-js)
to get last modified date of Wikipedia pages. While referring [MediaWiki API help](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=main#main.2Fdatatypes) I find various formats for Timestamp but I am unable find syntax to use it. The following code :

```
var mwjs = new MediaWikiJS('https://en.wikipedia.org', { action: 'query', prop: 'revisions', titles: 'Main_Page' }, function (data) {
        'use strict';
        var pages = data.query.pages;
        alert('Main page of Wikipedia last edited by: ' + pages[Object.keys(pages)[0]].revisions[0].timestamp);
    });
```

gives default format. How can I change it to any other required format?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the various date formats you linked to are for *input* that you can specify to the API, not the *output* that you get from the API.

If you want to show the date in a different format to the user, you should use the date parsing and formatting functions of the language you use.

Comment: Maybe the change in date formats is directly not available in API, but is it same for HTTP requests too? At [API:Main_page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) in a basic example it is shown how we can retrieve data in json or other format. So can we format dates by specifying any additional parameters or in any of the cases we need to explicitly change format by date parsing in the language we using?

Comment: I don't understand the question, there is no difference between the API and the HTTP requests you use to access it.

Comment: by API in above comment I mean [mediawiki-js](https://github.com/brettz9/mediawiki-js) Javascript Library which ultimately uses Mediawiki API. Sorry for any confusions I created. So my question exactly means: I want to know that if we can directly get data having different date format than the default with MediaWiki API irrespective of [API:Client Code/API access libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code) (eg. mediawiki-js which I selected) we use.